# Sublime Text C++ Build System

Tags: c++, sublimetext3, build-system

I use the following compiler settings to compile my C++ code:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -O2 -fwrapv -Wfloat-equal -Wconversion -std=c++17 A.cpp
```

But I am not sure how to setup the build system for the purpose, nor I want to try myself! I doubt that I may mess up the configuration (because I did once).

So I need help to configure my build system for the above compiler settings. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This build system works in my machine, basically its the default C++ build system with the extra options,

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "g++ -Wall -Wextra -O2 -fwrapv -Wfloat-equal -Wconversion -std=c++17 \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\"",
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c++",

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "shell_cmd": "g++ -Wall -Wextra -O2 -fwrapv -Wfloat-equal -Wconversion -std=c++17 \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\" && \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\""
        }
    ]
}
```

You can place it in `/Users/{user}/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User` directory for MacOs, `C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User` in Windows or `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User` in Linux.
You can call the file something like `C++17.sublime-build` to differentiate it from the default build system.