# Sublime Text 3 problem with compiling C++ programm

Tags: c++, sublimetext3

So I have following problem, I installed MinGW and it works I can manually compile my program using this `g++ filename` in cmd, and it crates exe file which I can run in cmd and see result. But when I try to use sublime text 3 and run it from there there is following error "[WinError 2] The specified file could not be found".

This is build system which I found and tried to use:

```
{
"shell_cmd": "g++ -Wall -Wextra -O2 -fwrapv -Wfloat-equal -Wconversion -std=c++17 \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\"",
"file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
"working_dir": "${file_path}",
"selector": "source.c++",

"variants":
[
    {
        "name": "Run",
        "shell_cmd": "g++ -Wall -Wextra -O2 -fwrapv -Wfloat-equal -Wconversion -std=c++17 \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\" && \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\""
    }
]
}
```

Which I found here [Sublime Text C++ Build System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62434508/sublime-text-c-build-system)

Im not sure if I describe my problem correctly so if you have more question feel free to ask.

Thanks :)

Comment: Is g++ on your path?

Comment: Yes, I did add it.

Comment: Did you reboot afterwards or otherwise reload your environment variables?

Comment: Ok, I got this. Thanks for your help.