# Can I view default C build files for Sublime?

Tags: c, sublimetext3

I searched my entire operating system for *.sublime-build files and could not find any non user created files.

Where are these files?

I just wanted a starting point to create my own build system for C language, and simply modify the default build system to put output files in a folder called `out` so that my source directory is not cluttered with executable files.

I'm just trying to get started on a build system for C.

ChatGPT gave me this as an example:

```
{
    "cmd": ["gcc", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/../out/${file_base_name}"],
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c"
}
```

but I get the error:

```
ld: can't open output file for writing: /Users/c/top/courses/course-c/../out/00-hello, errno=2 for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Only other similar question I could find on SO was for [C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62434508/sublime-text-c-build-system)

Comment: Are you sure there is a folder in the path ${file_path}/../out/ ? If not you can make it using `"mkdir": {"path": ["${file_path}/../out"]}`

Comment: The question you're asking and the problem you're having don't seem to be related? The builds that ship with Sublime for C/C++ put the output directly into the folder that the input file is in, because it's guaranteed to exist; as mentioned by @AliSheikhpour you need to make sure that it exists if you're going to dump the output into other locations.

Answer (score 0):

> Where are these files?

They are stored in the default language packages that Sublime Text ships with, e.g. the build system for "C single file" lives in `[install dir]\Packages\C++.sublime-package`. The sublime-package files are zip archives, use your favourite zip capable program to open them.

You can also open the build system files directly in Sublime by `Command palette -> View Package File -> type ".sublime-build" and search for the one you want to view -> enter`

Comment: After I hit enter ... it just opens up an empty file with that name.  Not very useful.

Comment: Make sure to select a .sublime-build file, not a .sublime-package file. If you do the latter, it opens an empty file